# ¿Cómo hago para solucionar un error en una condición?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de imprimir los números positivos de un arreglo con recursividad, pero al escribir la condición de `if(arreglo[i] > 0)` me da error.

Ya probe ponerlo en varias partes, pero no me deja compilar. Aquí está el código que el único error es en la condición que no me deja compilar.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ejerciciorecursividad
{
    class Program
    {

        static int SumaPositivos(int[] arreglo, int i)
        {   
                if (i == 5 - 1)
                {
                    return arreglo[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    return arreglo[i] + SumaPositivos(arreglo, i + 1);         
                }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arreglo = new int[] { 1, -5, 3, 4, -5 };
            Console.WriteLine("la Suma de los numeros positivos es "+ SumaPositivos(arreglo,0));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Será porque te falta el return después del `if (arreglo[i] > 0)`?

Comment: pero que devolveria ese return?

Comment: En el if (i == 5 - 1), no tiene sentido esa resta, siempre pero siempre te dara 4, directamente coloca el if (i == 4), esa resta deberia ser para un valor que cambie y siempre le debas quitar 1 o lo que haga falta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo probé de la siguiente manera y compiló, espero te sirva:

```
static int SumaPositivos(int[] arreglo, int i)
    {

        if (arreglo[i] > 0) {

            if (i == 5 - 1)
            {
                return arreglo[i];
            }
            else
            {
                return arreglo[i] + SumaPositivos(arreglo, i + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Lo que modifiqué fue lo siguiente:

En el sector del if que te generaba el error agregué los caracteres `{}` de inicio y cierre del bloque, ademas su contra condición `else` que retorna el valor 0 debido a que si o si tiene que retornar un valor al ser recursividad, entonces de esta manera, cualquier rama de la condición tendrá algo que retornar, ya sea al programa principal o a la función, es posible que debas modificar las cosas que retornas, revisa y modifica a tu conveniencia, Saludos!

Comment: Considera explicar el porqué debe ir ese else y porqué debe retornar un valor la función. Puede ser que el OP no entienda la razón ;)

Comment: Está bien, gracias por la observacion, ahora lo edito...

Comment: ok, muchisimas gracias braian lo probare con el return 0, si te entendi psdt

Comment: Este código lamentablemente no funcionará, porque si el primer elemento del *array* es un entero negativo, la condición `arreglo[i] > 0` dará `false` y esto hace que el método retorne `0`. Pero realmente esto no es lo que debería hacer la rutina, ya que lo ideal sería ir verificando si en el *array* hay elementos positivos.

Comment: MrDave1999 También noté eso, pero solo me limité a explicar la duda que el tenia, en ocasiones explicar de mas causa mas confusión.

Comment: @lizett si la respuesta te sirvio marcala como aceptada, esa es la forma de dar las gracias.

Comment: @Braianvargas, ese metodo no funciona porque tiene return por todos lados entonces sale del metodo en todos lados y no se vuelve a llamar a si mismo. Mas alla de compilar deberia funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Para no crear variables globales

```
static int SumaPositivos(int[] arreglo, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Indice\t\t"+ i);
        if(arreglo[i] >= 0 || i == 0){
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento a sumar:\t"+ arreglo[i]);
            if(i == 0){
                // en caso de que el primero sea negativo (o lo reemplaza #evita error)
                if(arreglo[i] > 0)
                    return arreglo[i];
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            else
                return arreglo[i] + SumaPositivos(arreglo, i-1);
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento ignorado:\t"+ arreglo[i]);
            // -1 en caso de que el ultimo sea negativo (o lo reemplaza #evita error)
            return 0 + SumaPositivos(arreglo, i-1);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arreglo = new int[]{ -10, -24, 45, -3, 54, -58 };
        Console.WriteLine("la Suma de los numeros positivos es "+ SumaPositivos(arreglo, arreglo.Length-1));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Las salidas eran cosa mía hace rato que no hago estas cosas que me costo, mas que nada cuando el primer o ultimo elemento son negativos

Answer (score -1):

Lo podes resolver de esta manera para que la suma de bien, porque si hace el `return` se sale del metodo y no se llama asi mismo.
Le pasas un parametro extra, del tamaño del array para que conste que sea menor y se vuelva a llamar a si mismo, hasta que corte y vaya sumando.
Te faltaria declarar una variable `int total` fuera del metodo.

```
    static int total = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arreglo1 = new int[] { 1, -5, 3, 4, -5 };
        Console.WriteLine(SumaPositivos(arreglo1, 0, 5));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int SumaPositivos(int[] arreglo, int i, int tam)
    {
        if (i < tam)
        {
            if (arreglo[i] > 0)
            {
                total += arreglo[i];
            }
            SumaPositivos(arreglo, i + 1, tam);
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Si sumaPositivos no toma el return,entonces no sirve. Esto no funciona asi como esta escrito

Comment: yo lo probe y funciona perfecto

Comment: Ejecuta. Pero no suma los positivos de un arreglo. No hay nada que agarre el return de sumapositivos cuando se la llama recursivamente

Comment: Salvo que total sea global... entonces esta funcion no tiene sentido que sea recursiva ni que tenga un return. Hay una confusion de conceptos aca.